# gatsby js with godaddy results in 503 error

Tags: drupal, headless, json-api, http-status-code-503, gatsby

I am running a 'headless' (decoupled) Drupal install on GoDaddy hosting, using JSON API and GatsbyJS.

Drupal > Gatsby works well locally, but when hosted with GoDaddy the Gatsby 'develop' command results in a 503 error, which I assume is GoDaddy reaching its maximum connection limit, i.e. getting overwhelmed with Gatsby's speed and responding with a denial of service.

Has anyone else encountered this, have a work around, or suggest alternate hosting that is more compatible with Gatsby JS?

Many thanks in advance -- on a tight deadline, so really appreciate any insight.